# Is it better to initialize a variable with malloc?

Tags: c, function, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, coding-efficiency

If I have a pointer in a function and I know what size it is, would it be better to use `malloc` when the pointer is initialized?
For example,
if I have a function, would it be better to do this

```
int * func(int size){
    int * ptr = (int *) malloc(size);
    //some code
    return ptr;
}
```

or this

```
int * func(int size){
    int * ptr;
    ptr = (int *) malloc(size);
    //some code
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: I would use `int * ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * size);`  I wonder if your code's  `size` takes into account the  `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Please define the term "better".

Comment: The second is not an initialiser, but an (initial) assignment.

Comment: @JensGustedt Is it more efficient in any way?

Comment: I would be surprised if the code is not identical.  Using an initializer with an automatic declaration is equivalent to following the declaration with an assignment.

Comment: Efficient is completely the wrong question here. You would be comparing the call overhead of `malloc` to shaving off one or two instructions. First, ensure that your code is readable, then that it is correct.

Comment: @Olaf in C, for scalar types, `T a = b;` is defined to be the same as `T a; a = b;` so it is not a huge issue.

Comment: @M.M: Please remember this will be read by other beginners who think this can be adopted for compound types like arrays and `struct`s.

Answer (score 4):

The first form is better in the sense that your code is safer; you know that `ptr` will either contain a valid address value or `NULL` before its first use.

The second form leaves you open to problems if you accidentally use `ptr` before assigning a valid address to it; without an explicit initializer, its initial value is *indeterminate*, and if you accidentally use `ptr` before assigning to it, your code may or may not crash immediately.

I can pretty much guarantee that there will be no measurable difference in runtime performance or memory footprint, nor will there be a measurable difference in build time.

You should *always* initialize your pointer variables at declaration time, and IMO you should defer their declaration until you actually *need* them.  IOW, instead of writing something like this:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int *ptr = NULL;
  /**
   * several dozen lines of code
   */
  ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr * number_of_elements );
  /**
   * do stuff with ptr
   */
}
```

it's better to write this:

```
void foo( void )
{
  /**
   * several dozen lines of code
   */
  int *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr * number_of_elements );
  /**
   * do stuff with ptr
   */
}
```

Granted, this is only possible from C99 on; if you're using a C89 or earlier compiler, all declarations *must* come before any executable statements in a block.

The usual nits:

- Don't cast the result of `malloc`; as of C89 it's unnecessary, and under C89 compilers can mask a bug.  It's still required for C++, but if you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.  If you're writing code that has to build as C and C++, hide your memory allocation code behind an interface and implement it differently for each.  I'm not kidding.
- Use `sizeof *ptr` instead of `sizeof (type)` in the `malloc` call, such as

  ```
  int *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr * number_of_elements );
  ```

  It will reduce maintenance headaches if you ever change the type of `ptr` (say from `int *` to `unsigned *` or `long *`).

Comment: In C89 you can usually achieve the same goal by starting a block with the declaration.  If this makes your code ugly then consider not having such large functions.

Comment: If writing code that has to build for C and C++ , another way is to put the allocation code in a C file  (C++ allows for C objects to be linked)

Answer (score 2):

> "Is it more efficient in any way?"

Little or no significant run-time efficiency difference. [@Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070102/is-it-better-to-initialize-a-variable-with-malloc/36071638#comment59787877_36070102)

> Is it better to initialize a variable with malloc?

Yes it is better to initialize a variable with something rather than nothing.  Neither OP code snippets is that good for other reasons. No need to cast `malloc()` result.  `size_t` is the better argument type than `int`.  `size_t` is the right size type to hold the size of all arrays and the result of `sizeof()`.

```
int *func(int size) {
  int *ptr = malloc(size);
  //some code
  return ptr;
}
```

It is unclear if `size` refers to the number of elements in the `int` array or the supposed size of a single `int`.  Recommend:

```
int *func(size_t array_n) {
  int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * array_n);
  //some code
  return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

They are basically the same. I want to just give you an advice, always initialize a pointer with NULL (you didn't in the second snippet). Also, remember to free() memory for your dynamically allocated variable inside a function.

Comment: He wants to initialize the pointer with the result of `malloc`.   adding an extra `NULL` before that is not only redundant, but may hide a compiler warning about accidental use of the variable, and makes it harder for the compiler to optimize (e.g. the optimizer might share space for that pointer with another variable that is not used after the malloc).

Comment: @M.M I've been teached to always initializes variables. Pointer are variables, hence I initialize them with NULL. To me it seems that initializing variables is a good practice for a lot of reasons.

Comment: It seems like bad practice to me , for the reasons I mentioned.  Either way, the problem should be avoided by not declaring the variable until you are ready to initialize it.

Comment: @M.M So, is it only an "optimization problem"?

Comment: Yes, and also readability and code-correctness.   No initializer indicates that the variable is not intended to be read yet, and modern compilers will emit a warning if you do try to read it.

Comment: @M.M I usually compile with -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ansi, never had a single warning like this. I'll ask my teacher further information, and as I think we are going off-topic I may ask a question here on SO later on. By the way I appreciate your effort. I'm still studying C and everything I can learn is more than accepted and welcome

Comment: @M.M Your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070102/is-it-better-to-initialize-a-variable-with-malloc/36071638#comment59789505_36070486) bring up a valid consideration for _not_ initializing a variable.  This relies on a compiler warning though.  Given some compilers might not warn, or the path from declaration to first usage may be not obvious, errant code with UB could be compiled.  IAC, sounds like we agree delaying declaration until use solves many problems.

Comment: [See here](http://goo.gl/Xi93x5) for example of warning. I downvoted mainly because this doesn't constitute an answer to the original question, if you wanted to give this advice it would have been better just to leave a comment under the question

Comment: @chux errant code without UB may also be a serious problem, in practice  (the function may contain a logic error, e.g. the coder meant to read some other variable, but reads our variable by mistake and doesn't realize, and so calls the launch missiles function)